# Getting the image name using autoencoder on tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using this tensorflow image search script:
https://www.kaggle.com/jonmarty/using-autoencoder-to-search-images

```
def search(image):
    hidden_states = [sess.run(hidden_state(X, mask, W, b),
                     feed_dict={X: im.reshape(1, pixels), mask:  
                     np.random.binomial(1, 1-corruption_level, (1, pixels))})
                     for im in image_set]

    query = sess.run(hidden_state(X, mask, W, b),
                     feed_dict={X: image.reshape(1,pixels), mask: np.random.binomial(1, 1-corruption_level, (1, pixels))})

    starting_state = int(np.random.random()*len(hidden_states)) #choose random starting state
    best_states = [imported_images[starting_state]]
    distance = euclidean_distance(query[0], hidden_states[starting_state][0]) #Calculate similarity between hidden states
    for i in range(len(hidden_states)):
        dist = euclidean_distance(query[0], hidden_states[i][0])
        if dist <= distance:
            distance = dist #as the method progresses, it gets better at identifying similiar images
            best_states.append(imported_images[i])
    if len(best_states)>0:
        return best_states
    else:
        return best_states[len(best_states)-101:]
```

I'm wondering about if it's possible to know the image name (e.g: homer.jpg). I'm lost and I don't know what should I add in the code to know that.. That's the part of the script where I print the results:

```
 print(len(results))
slots = 0
plt.figure(figsize = (125,125))
for im in results[::-1]: #reads through results backwards (more similiar images first)
    plt.subplot(10, 10, slots+1) 
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)); plt.axis('off')
    slots += 1
```

Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the search function.

Specifically, look at the line:

```
best_states.append(imported_images[i])
```

If you want to map between the images returned and the filenames, you need to record and return that index, `i`.  Consider adding a `best_states_index` variable and returning both or simply replacing `imported_images[i]` with `i` and using that to access both the filename and the image data.

More explicitly:

```
def search(image):
    hidden_states = [sess.run(hidden_state(X, mask, W, b),
                     feed_dict={X: im.reshape(1, pixels), mask:  
                     np.random.binomial(1, 1-corruption_level, (1, pixels))})
                     for im in image_set]

    query = sess.run(hidden_state(X, mask, W, b),
                     feed_dict={X: image.reshape(1,pixels), mask: np.random.binomial(1, 1-corruption_level, (1, pixels))})

    starting_state = int(np.random.random()*len(hidden_states)) #choose random starting state
    best_states = [imported_images[starting_state]]
    best_states_index = [starting_state]
    distance = euclidean_distance(query[0], hidden_states[starting_state][0]) #Calculate similarity between hidden states
    for i in range(len(hidden_states)):
        dist = euclidean_distance(query[0], hidden_states[i][0])
        if dist <= distance:
            distance = dist #as the method progresses, it gets better at identifying similiar images
            best_states.append(imported_images[i])
            best_states_index.append(i)
    if len(best_states)>0:
        return best_states, best_states_index
    else:
        return best_states[len(best_states)-101:], best_states_index[len(best_states)-101:]
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you a lot for your answer! :)
I can't underdtand you.. I try to add the `best_states_index` like:
`best_states_index.append(i)` but I think I'm doing it wrong..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you tried and why it appears to be wrong?

Comment: Thank you John! I added your modified search function and whe I run the results function I get this:

`-----------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-97e215d47bd5> in <module>()
      4 for im in results[::-1]: #reads through results backwards (more similiar images first)
      5     plt.subplot(10, 10, slots+1)
----> 6     plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)); plt.axis('off')
      7     slots += 1

TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`